# I want the webpage to fit mobile view without being able to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website scales dynamically on desktop without creating scrollbars perfectly, but when I try using safari or google chrome on a mobile device to use it, it seems it may be fitting to the full device length (including under the address bar) rather than just the usable viewing space.

I've uploaded it to this domain-
http://asterisk.best/

**index.js**

```
import styles from '../styles/sliderpage.module.css'

import Head from 'next/head'

import './api/mouseListener'
import './api/colorChange'
    
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.slide_wrap}>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
      <div className={styles.main}>
        <Head>
          <title>Asterisk Digital Consulting</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Site under construction." />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" />
        </Head>
        <div id="left-side" className="side">
          <h2 className="title">
            Asterisk Digital <br />will
            <span className="fancy"> brb.</span>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="right-side" className="side">
          <h2 className="title">
            Asterisk Digital <br />will
            <span className="fancy"> brb.</span>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**globals.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Rubik&display=swap');
:root {
  --dark: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  --yellow: rgb(253, 216, 53);
  --blue: rgb(98, 0, 234);
  
  --c1: rgb(18, 39, 6);
  --c2: rgb(131, 204, 124);
  
  --left-color: var(--c1);
  --right-color: var(--c2);
}

body {  
  background-color: var(--dark);
  margin: 0px;
}

.side {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  place-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.side .title {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-size: 8vw;
  margin: 0px 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
}

.side .fancy {
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

#left-side {
  background-color: var(--left-color);
  width: 60%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#left-side .title {  
  color: white;  
}

#left-side .fancy {
  color: var(--right-color);
}

#right-side {
  background-color: var(--right-color);
}

#right-side .title {
  color: var(--dark);
}

#right-side .fancy {
  color: white;
}
```

**sliderpage.module.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Rubik&display=swap');
.slide_wrap {
  --dark: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  
  --c1: rgb(6, 21, 39);
  --c2: rgb(124, 145, 204);
  
  --left-color: var(--c1);
  --right-color: var(--c2);
}

.main {  
  background-color: var(--dark);
  margin: 0px;
}
```

I tried using a viewport meta tag suggested elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable scroll completely , add overflow hidden to your body tag such as

```
body {  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Think this is almost good, but want my text to be centered still on mobile. Updated domain with the change

Comment: you didnt mentioned about centering text on mobile, for that yo can add `text-align: center;` to body, i will update the answer

Comment: No I don't mean centered in that sense. The text is displayed in the center of the grid, but with overflow: hidden, the center of the grid does not appear in the center of the screen anymore. I am looking to maintain its relative position even when on a mobile device in portrait.